# Python randint not equal to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to use `random.randint` to randomly generate a single `int` between a range, e.g. `randint(-2,2)`, however, it could possibly generate `0`, which is not expected, so I am wondering is there a way to make it not equal to `0`. Or just use a loop until `randint(-2,2)` not generate `0`, and get the output.

cheers

Comment: Just make a list and use `random.choice`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `randint()` then; it picks an integer from a continuous range of values, not a discrete set.

Use the [`random.choice()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) instead, passing in a list of *just* those integers you want to pick from:

```
random.choice([-2, -1, 1, 2])
```

This'll return a random value from that list.

Comment: I just want to get a single `int`, not a list actually

Comment: @daiyue `random.choice` will give you an int from that list

Comment: @daiyue random.choice picks one value from the list, so that's exactly what you'd get.